# PHP Set Editable Checkbox Variable In Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of items that can be changed by the user. Each item in that array can be edited by the simplified rows below:

```
foreach( $items as $item) {
   <tr> 
       <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item['name'] ); ?>" /></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>
       <input type="hidden" name="items[<?php echo $i; ?>][ischecked]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $item['ischecked'] ); ?>" />
   </tr>
 }
```

`$item['name']` is successfully be changed, what I'm asking is how to setup the Checkbox to store the value `true`, if the checkbox is checked to `$item['ischecked']`?

Comment: Are you asking if in your database you have `$item['ischecked']` as filled, how to make the check box be checked when you generate the html? If so, you can just do `<input type="checkbox" name="" value="<?php if(!empty($item['ischecked'])) echo true ?>" <?php if(!empty($item['ischecked'])) echo 'checked' ?> />`. If you don't mean this, I don't know what you need; you need to be clearer in your explanation.

Comment: Also, I am somewhat surprised the inputs generate values without `name` attributes.

Comment: Yes you are right theres also meant to be a hidden input with the name set, I've updated my initial question code

Answer (score 0):

Using the hidden input seem like a workaround rather than a clean, direct solution.

Can you modify the following snippets for your situation?

```
foreach($items as $i=>$item){
    echo "<tr> ";
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name[$i]\" value=\"",esc_attr($item['name']),"\" /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check_name[$i]\" value=\"true\"",(isset($_POST["check_name[$i]"])?" checked":"")," /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    // declare a variable for use in future queries, change/use this as/if needed
    $check[$i]=(isset($_POST["check_name[$i]"])?"true":"false"); 
}
```

I didn't test this solution, so let me know if something is dead wrong.